# Mongo Collection with custom transformation step

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a mongo collection where each object needs a conversion step to/from the custom object my code needs.

For example, my custom object has two functions:

```
MyObject.fromMongo
MyObject.toMongo
```

Now I want to make sure that every read/write in my collection goes through those functions. Currently I can customize which fields are saved (`toMongo`) using `toBSON` but I have not found a way to do the symetrical / opposite operation. Something to customize how the Cursor will translate the stored object.

I want a basic ODM (just the transformation step) without a whole different API. So something like Mongoose would be out of question.

Comment: Why do you need to go to BSON? What are you writing? Surely just go to a regular JavaScript object and let the driver do the rest.

Comment: Without `toBSON` I would be forcing the collection user to type the transformation step (ie: rename fields). Also I do not need to return BSON data, just the object shape, which is exactly what I want.

Comment: You appear to be missing the point. This is JavaScript. Any plain JavaScript object simply inserts into MongoDB. The driver takes care of the rest. If anything you might have a more complex class that you simply want a `.toObject()` method on. You don't really want to touch BSON unless you you are writing a "low level" interface to MongoDB over the wire protocol itself. This is not a userland thing. So you're not really explaining your intent and appear confused about how you are meant to interact with the database. Enlighten me if you believe I'm wrong, but I think you missed the intent.

Comment: You know that in the Mongo driver, an object with a toBSON method does not return a BSON object. Right?

Comment: No. Please spend some time reading some documentation. Your question does not make any sense since it's JavaScript not Java, and there is no need to "serialize" anything. Pointing you to the [Node.JS driver Documentation Reference](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/). There should be links back to the core documentation which you should also spend some time reading.